# Change home screen wallpaper on jailbreak iphone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, homescreen

I am trying to write an app for jailbreak iphone. 
Basically I want to change the home screen wallpaper programatically.

I have got that it can be changed by writing to some /var/Library but exactly how to write to this file in the coding and how to set the permissions

I have learnt that such app need to be run as root. What needs to be done to run the iphone app as root??

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 4.2.1, the wallpapers are "cpbitmap" files in `/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/`. I'm not aware of any Objective-C code to write to these files, but there should be something out there that you can use. Prior to 4.2.1, the wallpapers are JPEGs in the same folder.

Once you've copied over these images, a respring should make it appear.